# Gitlab-CI - Runner can't pull docker image - authorization token required

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-api

I am using **Omnibus Gitlab version 10.7.3-ee** .
I pushed a docker image on my own registry with a personal access token with success.
But when I want to build from this image in the Gitlab CI pipeline, I got the following error in the gitlab interface :

```
Running with gitlab-runner 10.6.0 (xxxxxxx)
on my-runner xxxxxxx
Using Docker executor with image gitlab.example.com/myproject/myimage1 ...
Pulling docker image gitlab.example.com/myproject/myimage1 ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: Error: No such image: gitlab.example.com/myproject/myimage1
Will be retried in 3s ...
```

On the gitlab server side, I got in */var/log/gitlab/registry/current* :

```
level=warning msg="error authorizing context: authorization token required"
```

At the same time in */var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log* :

```
Processing by Gitlab::RequestForgeryProtection::Controller#index as */*
  Parameters: {"changes"=>"_any", "gl_repository"=>nil, "project"=>"myproject/project.git", "protocol"=>"ssh", "env"=>"{}", "key_id"=>"[FILTERED]", "secret_token"=>"[FILTERED]"}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
This CSRF token verification failure is handled internally by `GitLab::RequestForgeryProtection`
Unlike the logs may suggest, this does not result in an actual 422 response to the user
For API requests, the only effect is that `current_user` will be `nil` for the duration of the request
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Elasticsearch: 0.0ms)
```

What is happening here? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just checking, did you follow the steps here? https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#define-an-image-from-a-private-container-registry That is, do you have a DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG variable in your config file?

Comment: I did not have it. I just added it now and get a different error:

`ERROR: Preparation failed: Error response from daemon: Get https://gitlab.example.com/v2/myspace/myproject/image1/manifests/latest: unauthorized: HTTP Basic: Access denied` 

Notice that my user normally uses 2FA authentication.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved my own issue.
I don't why I have suddenly been asked for credentials whereas I did not need it.

Using DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG variable did nothing to help me.

The solution was to log in from my private runner. Then it was able to pull the image.

```
docker login private-runner.example.com -u John -p mypassword
```

Then I pulled and logged out.

I don't know if it is a solution or a workaround... but later, I totally reinstalled my runner and I succeeded to pull without been log in...

Comment: It is working the second time because the credentials are stored for the registry at  ~/.docker/config.json file when you have been logged in previously. I am doing the wrong way too, but I am planning into my environment to set up properly DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG variable.